# DRYer method for if-else conditional statement?

Tags: ruby

How to write DRYer code for this in a model:

```
a = 10
b = 6
if a == b
  a = 20
else
  a
end
```

Basically, `a` remains `a = 10` when `a != b`.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with your else statement?

Comment: @dcaswel Do we really want that tag added? Those led here by it might be, er, underwhelmed.

Comment: What a ridiculous contrived example. The real answer is to not have assignments and then immediately check them. Perhaps if you put in more of the actual code, the responses can be better.

Comment: It's a simplified code. Data is retrieved from database.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 10
b = 6
a = 20 if a == b
```

If this is in a method and you want the last value of `a` to be returned:

```
a = 10
b = 6
a == b ? a = 20 : a
```

Comment: It returns boolean instead (for method 2).

Comment: If the second example is what is wanted, then use `a == b ? 20 : a`.

Comment: Method 2 doesn't return boolean, it returns the value of a.  The ternary operation has three segments, in our example a boolean as the first segment, and it's segment 2 or segment 3 that's returned based on whether the boolean is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the third one :

You can also use short circuit operator `and`

```
a = 10
b = 6
a == b and a = 20
```

Comment: That will return either false or 20

Comment: Yes, but the last statement of the question state's `Basically, a remains a = 10 when a != b`. So, my code will assign 20 to a if a == b otherwise do nothing